# Java8: How to replace the bitwise inclusive and ( &) by the function Predicate?

Tags: java, function, java-8

I want to use the function Predicate instead of the & operator. it means that I want that "Second Test is passed !!" be printed after the execution of my code.

How can I do it ?

```
public class BitwiseInclusiveAND{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Predicate<String> condition1 = (Predicate<String>) (arg -> arg != null);
        final Predicate<String> condition2 = (Predicate<String>) (arg -> {
            System.out.println("Second Test is passed !!");
            return arg.equals("Hello");
        });
        Predicate<String> equalsStrings
                = condition1.and(condition2); // Here I want to execute the condition2 even if condition 1 = true 
        System.out.println(equalsStrings.test("Hello"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where is the bitwise operation here? Do you mean the logical or operator?

Comment: @AndyTurner  I want to replace "condition1.or(condition2)" by a bitiwse exclusive or

Comment: For of all, `|` is the *inclusive* OR, not the exclusive OR (which would be `^`). Second, there is no sense in repeatedly saying “*bitwise*” when you want to combine boolean values, not bits. Besides that, the only combination that makes sense here, is a conditional AND, `arg!=null && arg.equals("Hello")` as anything else may cause a `NullPointerException`…

Comment: @Holger my question is better now. thank you :)

Comment: For AND, there is no “inclusive” or “exclusive” variant. It’s just the “logical And (`&`)” or “conditional And (`&&`)”. However, asking for the logical And, knowing that this will lead to a `NullPointerException` in the second predicate, still does not make much sense. Using the conditional And, not executing `arg.equals("Hello")` when `arg` is `null` is usually what a programmer wants. But [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976296/2711488) is still the same; you can create whatever combining predicate you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just implement the predicate yourself:

```
Predicate<String> or = s -> condition1.test(s) & condition2.test(s);
```

Replacing the `&` with whatever other operator you might want.